# python skip that process when i get an error

Tags: python, telethon

```
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UserAlreadyParticipantError: The authenticated user is already a participant of the chat (caused by ImportChatInviteRequest)
```

*my only request is for it to ignore and continue processing when i get this error*

```
with open('numaralar.csv', 'r')as f:
    str_list = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f)]
    po = 0
    for pphone in str_list:
        phone = utils.parse_phone(pphone)
        po += 1
        print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + f"Giriş {phone}")
        client = TelegramClient(f"sessions/{phone}", 2392599, '7e14b38d250953c8c1e94fd7b2d63550')
        client.connect()
        if not client.is_user_authorized():
            try:
                client.send_code_request(pphone)
                client.sing_in(pphone,input('Kodu Gir :'))
                print('')
                client.sign_in(pphone)
            except SessionPasswordNeededError:
                password = input('2fa Şifresini Gir: ')
                print('')
                client.sign_in(password=password)
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + f"fuatcim BUNLA ZATEN GİRMİSSİN AMK")
                continue
            

            
        gplink = 'qDPUgvuTiCliNzdk'
        client(ImportChatInviteRequest(gplink))
        print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + f"fuatcim gruba girdim askim")
```

I tried something like this but failed
how can i do something it seems easy but i am just starting to learn

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the error is caused by ImportChatInviteRequest()
so you have to surround that part with a try - except block.

```
try:
    gplink = 'qDPUgvuTiCliNzdk'
    client(ImportChatInviteRequest(gplink))
    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + f"fuatcim gruba girdim askim")
except:
    pass   # When there is an exception, do nothing
```